# How to do a task only once every 200 milliseconds

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I need to post ie 25 requests to webserver in a for loop. The webserver is limited to only 5 calls per second for some reason. So I need to make sure 200 miliseconds have passed since the last request. I have this code below as a demo (the actual code is inside a WCF service), but I believe Thread.Sleep is not the best way to go. Are there any alternatives, Theaded or otherwise?

```
class Program
{
    private static long lastRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) { PostData(); }

        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PostData()
    {
        var elapsedMilliseconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastRun).TotalMillliseconds;

        if (elapsedMilliseconds < 200)
        {
            var pause = 200 - elapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Pausing for " + pause);

            // pause
            Thread.Sleep(pause);
        }
// HttpPost here

        lastRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Console.WriteLine("Job done at {0}.{1}", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try Timer class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Given your requirements, I'd send the requests in batches of 5, with a full one second delay between batches. Also, Thread.Sleep() is a _great_ way to do this, as long as you spawn a background thread to handle it. The only reason not to use thread.Sleep() is that it blocks the execution of the main thread.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn There's more to it - this is being doing on a server as part of a service, so you should try to avoid blocking.  (From comment in my answer)

Comment: Timers would fire an event every 200ms, but what if one calls takes longer than 200ms. Then the conditions would be breached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this is a console application, `Thread.Sleep()` will actually work quite well.  It blocks, but there really isn't any other work to be done while this is blocking, so there's little downsides.

If this were a GUI app, service, or other scenario where blocking is bad, however, then I would recommend using asynchronous methods, and `await Task.Delay(pause)` instead, which would allow the UI to continue processing messages.  This doesn't matter in a console application, though, so there is little or no downside to your current approach.

This would involve making your main method asynchrnous

```
static async Task PostDataMultipleTimes(int times)
{
     for (int i=0;i<times;++i)
     {
         var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
         PostData(); // PostData doesn't need to sleep/wait/etc anymore

         var ms = (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
         if (ms < 200)
             await Task.Delay(200 - ms);
     }
}
```

Note that `PostData` no longer needs any logic related to blocking - it would just post your relevant data.

This would likely be possible to accomplish in .NET 4. with task continuations, but I'd likely just use `Sleep` as the logic gets fairly ugly, very quickly.

Comment: Sorry not to clarify. The console application is only for demonstration. The actual code lives inside a WCF service.

Comment: @JensRud - so you receive a message, but a dependent system you work with can only handle 5 requests per second? Can you update your question to reflect its WCF, as WCF does have throttling controls in it.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - `await` is .NET 5. The question is for .NET 4, but good product advertisement ;-)

Comment: Updated tags with WCF.

Comment: @Reed Copsey. Great solution, I might be able to update the solution to .NET 4.5 after all. Then this would work, right?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz There is no .NET 5. .NET 4.5.2 was released yesterday. You are thinking of C# 5.0. You can also use async / await with .NET 4 by using the [async targeting pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) in conjunction with C# 5.

Comment: @Reed Copsey. How would I wait for all post to have completed? Since I don't actually want the main caller to continue untill all posts have finished?

Comment: @JensRud You'd jsut do `await PostDataMultipleTimes(25);` in the caller code